# Can't Connect To Network After Mac Address Spoof

Tags: mac-address

I know this has been asked before but no real answer has been given. I would spoof my mac address using either busybox manually or via apps and afterwards I would not be able to connect to wifi networks. I think the problem may be with ip problems and not the mac address. If I set up a static ip I can connect to the network but it would act as if I wasn't connected and no internet would be given. I connected to the network with my default mac and got internet access and found out the ip info and stuff and so I tried to spoof my mac address again and then set the static ip as that one and it would connect but yet again would get no internet. This makes no sense to me as it works fine on my computer.

Comment: MAC address filtering on the router?

Comment: No, there is no mac address filtering on the router. I just don't get why I can spoof my mac address on my computer and it works fine but not on my phone.

Comment: Try matching the details of that desktop and your phone. You can see the details in desktop by typing ipconfig /all in cmd and using Ping tools in android. Here's the link of that app - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ua.com.streamsoft.pingtools .

Comment: Also what tool do you use to change mac like mac address spoofer or Device id changer.

Comment: I've done it manually with busybox using ifconfig commands and I've tried literally every app in the app store for it.

Comment: Also, I've done that. I've used the same dns, same default gateway, same everything except static ip obviously.

Comment: I've used MAC adderess ghost for the very same purpose and it works really well. Also, what do you use to confirm a changed MAC address. Here's the link of the app - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=diewland.changemac&hl=en

Comment: I use the command busybox ifconfig to see that it was changed, and every time it was in fact, changed. I'll take a look at that app.

Comment: You can use Fing or ping tools to see the detailed list of network connection. I did MAC spoofing thousand times but never faced such an issue.

Comment: I have also used Fing to look at it and everything seemed fine but still faced the same problem. Others have been facing the same problem but no clear answer has been found.

Comment: I used the Mac Address Ghost app and I thought it had worked as it connected and I had internet but It didn't actually change the mac address at all

Comment: Why don't you try this guide on XDA. - https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2286440

Comment: Guide did not work. Still am having the same problem. I assure you I am doing everything correct

Comment: I can't help with this any further as this is the thing one cannot solve just by texting. But still, if there's something you want to know, you can message/tag me.

Comment: It seems that when it tries to connect to a network it is not actually using the spoofed mac address even though if I look using busybox ifconfig wlan0 which shows that it was changed but on my computer using adb logcat command shows otherwise. I have found the file that contains the mac address but it shows the mac address in hex and list it 4 different times as Intf0MacAddress, Intf1Maccaddress, and so on... If I could find out how to edit this I imagine I could change it, correct?